# Zooming part of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a web application in which I need to display an image which a grid superimposed on it. So when the user clicks on any one tile of that grid, that tile gets magnified.
I have the image with superimposed grid but cannot find a way to zoom parts of it. I am using jquery and javascript

Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a plugin like http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom